# How to use: WP_AJAX_GET_COMMENTS

Tags: functions, ajax, comments

I just found out `WP_AJAX_GET_COMMENTS($action)` function to retrieve comments on WordPress.
Someone know how to use it?

Thank you so much
Stefano

Comment: The documentation is available here: [`wp_ajax_get_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_ajax_get_comments/). (Note that the function is all lowercase, not UPPERCASE.)

Comment: Yes, but there aren't any examples. How to retrieve the comment using this function? I don't understand..

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_ajax_get_comments()

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/421535/edit) to include the code you're trying to debug. That might help us determine where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It is being used under `wp-admin/js/post.js` the function `commentsBox.get`. The purpose is to get Post comments. The UI related to it should be shown under the Comments page of WordPress. Though if you will further check the code, the selectors aren't present there. So there's no way you could use it just by calling out the function.